# How to parse zendesk ticket and act base on some scripting result

Tags: plugins

I looked into zendesk support which includes target action. That only allow me to notify an external server about the events happened in zendesk. This is only half of what I want, I also want to run a script over the content of zendesk ticket then generate a result that should be applied back to zendesk, e.g. a serial of keystrokes.

My current thought is to write a chrome extension that can parse the current page and try to extract the ticket context, then based on the ticket context, I can simulate some keystrokes.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the script on the external Server and then post back to Zendesk Ticket via API?